# Getting error when tried to update ubuntu :Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxmint-tr/araclar/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease 403 Forbidden

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I tried to update Ubuntu using :

```
sudo apt update
```

But I am getting error as follow:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxmint-tr/araclar/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxmint-tr/araclar/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/pygame/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

To workaround, I grepped all the enabled binary sources by running this command:

```
grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

which gave output:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/windscribe-repo.list:deb https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/thopiekar-ubuntu-pygame-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/pygame/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxmint-tr-ubuntu-araclar-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxmint-tr/araclar/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/swi-prolog-ubuntu-stable-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/swi-prolog/stable/ubuntu focal main
```

What should I do, any suggestions?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 0):

According to [https://launchpad.net/~linuxmint-tr/+archive/ubuntu/focalbase](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxmint-tr/+archive/ubuntu/focalbase) you need to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxmint-tr/focalbase

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I tried and got an error - E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxmint-tr/araclar/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxmint-tr-ubuntu-araclar-focal.list* /tmp/
sudo apt update
echo $?
```

If all goes ok, then ok. Else, just copy it back.